# How to debug inside classes in Xcode

Tags: ios7, xcode5, core-bluetooth

I am debugging a simple app using Xcode 5.0.2. When I try to examine the contents of a class, the debugger doesn't seem to know how to display the class.

For example, I have a variable which is of type CBService. Xcode correctly displays the class name to the right of the variable in the Local Variables window. However, when I click on the disclosure triangle next to the variable name, the variable expands and it says 'NSObject'. Which it is, ultimately. But that is not at all helpful. But Xcode will not show me the properties of the class. This makes debugging a problem, because I must look at memory without a template of how my class is stored.

I expect Xcode to have knowledge of the class and display its properties. Many lesser debuggers can do this.

I have included the CoreBluetooth Framework.

Does anyone know if/how this can be done?

Comment: Ummm aren't you just looking for the header file? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBService_Class/translated_content/CBService.html

Comment: No. I am looking to examine the contents of a variable within a class without doing a memory dump and counting bytes. I have not explicitly imported the CBService.h. But if I link in the CoreBluetooth.framework for the target, isn't that sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the values of properties, then you need to simply print them out. E.g.

```
(lldb) po peripheral.name
```

If you want more detail, then your best guess is the `description`

```
(lldb) po service
<CBMutableService: 0x155578d0 Primary = YES, UUID = Human Interface Device, 
Included Services = (null), Characteristics = ("<CBMutableCharacteristic: 
0x15687af0 UUID = Unknown (<08590f7e db05467e 875772f6 faeb13d4>), Value = 
(null), Properties = 0x18, Permissions = 0x3, Descriptors = (null),
SubscribedCentrals = (\n)>"
)>
```

Apple frameworks are closed source. Unlike classes in many other frameworks, Core Bluetooth classes don't have declared public ivars that you would like to see. It's probably intentional that you cannot scrutinize this data easily. I'm sure there are practices for doing that but in most cases the above methods work at least for me very well.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I am not looking for source code. I'm ok with that. I am looking for Xcode to display the contents of a data structure according to its header file definition. Showing a memory dump is unhelpful because I can't see what, say, the 3rd property is. Basically, I'm looking for a better way to view variables in the Debugger. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's suboptimal, but I'll take it. thanks for your help.